# Checking if window is open not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I programatically created a new window and frame, in order to navigate to a separate page (Authentication). Upon closing the window, I want to do some stuff, but the `if` statement is never returning false.

```
Window newWindow = new Window();
Page authentication = new Authentication();
Frame newFrame = new Frame();
newWindow.Title = "Authentication";
newWindow.Content = newFrame;
newFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(authentication);
newWindow.Show();
if (IsWindowOpen<Window>("Authentication") == false)
    {
    //DO THINGS HERE
    }
```

This is my `IsWindowOpen` method:

```
public static bool IsWindowOpen<T>(string name = null) where T : Window
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
           ? Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().Any()
           : Application.Current.Windows.OfType<T>().Any(w => w.Title.Equals(name));
    }
```

I manage to open the new window and run the separate page, but upon closing nothing happens. I've added a print line in the if statement to check, and it doesn't print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `Show()` won't block the main thread.
If you want to do something when the window closes you should handle `Closing` event and do things there.
If you want to block the current thread until the window is closed, you should use `ShowDialog()` instead.